# Загрузка данных в tableview после перехода

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Задача такова. Есть два viewcontroller, принадлежащих одному классу. На одном вью контроллере есть, скажем так, 4 кнопки. По нажатию на любую из них мы переходим на второй вью контроллер, в котором находится только tableview. Но! На каждое нажатие кнопки должны грузиться свои данные в tableview. Пробовал в ibaction на кнопку прописывать так:

```
[myArr addObject:@"Яблоки"];
[self.myTable reloadData];
```

Но ничего не обновляется в таблице.

Если добавлять данные в массив в viewDidLoad, то все прекрасно отображается, но мне нужно заполнять данные в ibaction, который привязан к каждой кнопке.

Если делать так:

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath* )indexPath{

```
[myArr addObject:@"Яблоки"];
[self.myTable reloadData];
```

}

То все работает. Но мне пока не нужно обрабатывать нажатия на ячейки.

Сталкивался-ли кто-нибудь с этим?

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vcToGo animated:YES];
```

Здесь чисто черный экран и подглючивание интерфейса при переходе на него.

Comment: убедитесь что [self.myTable reloadData]; запускается в главном потоке

Comment: А как это узнать? Я только-только начал. Перехожу с JAVA Андроид и очень тяжко все это дается....

Comment: @Alexander Sviridov установите брейкпоинт на нужной строке, запустите прогрпмму, слева посмотрите в каком потоке идет выполнение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в общем случае делается так:

1. вешаем action на кнопку, там грузим или выбираем из ранее загруженных необходимые данные
2. далее инициализируем любым из способ следующий UITableViewController, будь то init, initWithNib, или сториборд
3. в @interface второго UITableViewController добавляем @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *items;
4. сетим нужные данные в только что созданный контроллер и презентуем его на экран, например:

   - (IBAction)optioPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
         NSArray* itemsToGo = @[@"Apple", @"Orange", @"Pen-apple"];
         MyTableVC *vcToGo = [[MyTableVC alloc] init];
         vcToGo.items = itemsToGo;
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:vcToGo animated:YES];
     }

при условии, что в MyTableVC все нормально с UITableViewDataSource вы увидите ваши данные, переданные из одного экрана в другой

Comment: А что делать, если они оба вью контроллера принадлежат одному классу? И у меня второй - не TableViewController, а просто ViewController и в нем лежит tableview.

Comment: Это не важно, второй вполне может быть UIViewController с лежащей поверх таблицей, это уже дело вкуса и доп. функционала.

Comment: Эта схема будет немного сложнее при использовании UIStoryboardSegue для перехода на другой экран

Comment: Извиняюсь, может я покажусь слишком наглым, но...не могли бы вы создать для меня проект с двумя кнопками на одном вью контроллере, нажатия по которым ведут на второй вью контроллер с таблицей и грузят в нее свои данные, зависящие от нажатой кнопки? Очень прошу. Просто я привык один раз увидеть, чтобы потом понимать это.

Comment: И да, у меня как раз сториборды. Ну а переходы.... button ->push

Comment: Еще актуально? Могу помочь, просто только что увидел ваш комментарий